# How to crop PDF with no quality loss?

Tags: pdf

I have a very specific problem. User1 creates a multi-layered PDF project (some planimetries made by technical designers, engineers, etc) and User2 needs to crop single areas of this PDF project to save them as new PDFs.

All the editors that I've found mean the "crop function" just for removing blank spaces around the pages, not for cropping random portions of a single page. Windows built-in "Snipping tool" is not an option, since the DPI count is too low and the output extension is an image.

How can such cropping be done?

Comment: Take the snip using any cut tool, paste it in word file, and save the file as pdf. I hope this should work.

Comment: I thank you, but I don't need a snipping tool... :(

Comment: Can you please explain what is **multi-layered** PDF?

Comment: It's a sort of PDF derived (for my experience) from a project edited with a professional image editor. So it's an output extension more than a native one. It has got many layers, properly called, like a project planimetry: windows, doors, stairs and so on. All of them are single elements composing the PDF and they're selectable to place or remove them when you open the document. 
I can't explain it better than this, sorry.

Comment: Ok, what I understood is, your PDF is some kind of plan of an architecture. Well, 2 things you can do: > 1. Install Adobe Acrobat Pro and use it.
> 2. Install Openoffice suite and open PDF using OpenOffice Draw.

I used OpenOffice Suite last time when I needed to edit PDF. Its open source also.

Comment: I'll consider using Draw when I'll have the other 1-2 softwares tested in my company, thank you very much for the suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

[Sejda.com](https://www.sejda.com/) has a [**crop PDF**](https://www.sejda.com/crop-pdf) tool that allows you to specify the crop area on each page (or a single crop area for all pages if you preffer).

Works in a browser or as a [desktop PDF editor](https://www.sejda.com/desktop).

1. Open https://www.sejda.com/crop-pdf
2. Upload or select your PDF document
3. Select the area to crop
4. Apply changes and Download your cropped document.

You might need to combine this with [Extract PDF pages](https://www.sejda.com/extract-pdf-pages) to get a single cropped page from a multi-page document.

Web tools are free to use 3 times per hour, files up to 50 Mb and 200 pages.

Disclaimer: I'm one of the developers.

Comment: Your software is almost perfect, really. UI is great and easy to use. One thing: when I crop the portion that I need, the layers are not present on the new PDF, when I open it with my default software...

Comment: Please share the document with support and we'll take a closer look.

Answer (score -1):

For cropping a part of one page or from multiple pages, but one by one you can install and use Lightshot free application: https://app.prntscr.com/pl/index.html
I know, this application can create image or copy to clipboard and have other additional functions as mark etc. You can paste copied areas to Writer from LibreOffice and then use "Export as PDF" to have it in pdf format.

Comment: I thank you for your answer, but a screenshot application is not what I need :'(
Lightshot, by the way, seems so cool!